I can send notifications to the phone with FCMclient, but when I try to send them with httpclient, I get a 401 error (serverkey is the same). Whyy
I used two different code structures for phone notification.
I can send notifications to the phone with FCMclient,
here is the code,
FCMClient client = new FCMClient("AAAAnvb1kCQ:AP***********");
       var message = new Message()
        {
            To = deviceToken,
           Notification = new AndroidNotification()
           {
               Body = body,
               Title = title,
                Icon = "http://localhost:26896/Resimler/taleplerimsayfasiiconu.png"
            }
        };

        try
        {
            var result = await client.SendMessageAsync(message);
           return true;
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
        {
    return false;
}

I don't get any code errors. I keep getting 401 errors.when I try to send them with httpclient, I get a 401 error (serverkey is the same). Why
string server_api_key = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SERVER_API_KEY"];
        string firebaseUrl = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";

        var data = new Message
        {
            To = deviceToken,
            Data = new AndroidNotification
            {
                Message = body,
                Name = title
            }
        };

        var jsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("key", server_api_key);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var content = new StringContent(jsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var response = await client.PostAsync(firebaseUrl, content);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return true; // Indicate success
            }
            else
            {
                string errorContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return false;
            }
        }

I work in a corporate company. and the server also allowed access to the https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send link.
I can send notifications to the server using Postman. But there are no notifications coming through my application.
When I run it from a local PC and use fcmclient, a notification comes to the phone. When I write the other code I get a 401 error.

This api is deprecated
